# ffmpeg - Take Frame Accurate Screenshot

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot, frame

trying to find a way to take frame accurate screenshots with ffmpeg WITHOUT re-encoding the video.

When I use:

```
ffmpeg -ss -i input -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg
```

with -ss being hh:mm:ss.ms, not matter how I specify the milliseconds, it is never frame accurate with this command. it seems to be landing on the nearest keyframe (which is not accurate enough for my application).

So, my question is:

Without re-encoding the video (ergo specifying -ss flag AFTER the input) is there any way to pull frame accurate screenshots via ffmpeg ?

If not, is there another solution on Windows that would allow that via **command line** ?

Thanks !

---

ffmpeg log report part 1:

```
ffmpeg started on 2018-01-22 at 02:52:59
Report written to "ffmpeg-20180122-025259.log"
Command line:
"D:\\ffmpeg-3.4.1-win64-static\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -ss 1:31:25.9885 -i "V:\\Test\\BDMV\\STREAM\\00000.m2ts" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 -report output.jpg
ffmpeg version N-89674-g57d0c24132 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '1:31:25.9885'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'V:\Test\BDMV\STREAM\00000.m2ts'.
Reading option '-vframes' ... matched as option 'vframes' (set the number of video frames to output) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-q:v' ... matched as option 'q' (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) with argument '2'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option 'output.jpg' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url V:\Test\BDMV\STREAM\00000.m2ts.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 1:31:25.9885.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: V:\Test\BDMV\STREAM\00000.m2ts.
[NULL @ 000001e53135a680] Opening 'V:\Test\BDMV\STREAM\00000.m2ts' for reading
[file @ 000001e53135b740] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=50
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] stream=0 stream_type=1b pid=1011 prog_reg_desc=HDMV
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] stream=1 stream_type=86 pid=1100 prog_reg_desc=HDMV
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] stream=2 stream_type=90 pid=1200 prog_reg_desc=HDMV
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:3
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] parser not found for codec hdmv_pgs_subtitle, packets or times may be invalid.
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 000001e5313b4380] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] no picture 
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[h264 @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] max_analyze_duration 7000000 reached at 7008000 microseconds st:1
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 23.916667 0.014415
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 23.916667 0.014415
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 24.000000 0.002352
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 24.000000 0.007275
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 48.000000 0.009407
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 48.000000 0.013337
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 23.976024 0.000000
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 23.976024 0.000000
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 47.952048 0.000000
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] rfps: 47.952048 0.000000
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] start time for stream 2 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000001e53135a680] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:2494608 seeks:2 frames:828
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[NULL @ 000001e53135c940] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
Input #0, mpegts, from 'V:\Test\BDMV\STREAM\00000.m2ts':
  Duration: 01:39:08.15, start: 600.000000, bitrate: 25263 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011], 169, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100], 659, 1/90000: Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) ([134][0][0][0] / 0x0086), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Stream #0:2[0x1200], 0, 1/90000: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
Successfully opened the file.
```

Comment: Share full log. `-ss` after `-i` does not re-encode the video. Your video file remains untouched. No matter where you place the `-ss`, ffmpeg will have to decode the video stream and use the JPEG encoder to create the image file. How off is the output from the desired frame?

Comment: Hi Mulvya, the output is .jpg as per my code and the output is fine. My problem is that seeking is NOT frame accurate. So when I specify a timecode including milliseconds that should target a specific frame (e.g. 24 fps, one of those 24 frames), but ffmpeg does not. It always lands on main keyframes that the movie has. It was said in another thread that specifying -ss AFTER the input results in a more accurate seek, but ffmpeg would have to decode every frame up to the seek point, ergo it would take a very long time....

Comment: Need to see log to see what container and what messages ffmpeg is throwing.

Comment: I posted the full ffmpeg log report, see the next 2 answers below. Thanks !

Comment: @mike That's not what answers are for. Please put them into your original question.

Comment: @TheSHEEP: I can't put it into the originalpost as the chars count of the ffmpeg log exceeded the max post/answer limit of 30,000... so I had to split it up into two answers... unless there's a different way ?

Comment: any help on the question ?

Comment: is there any help on this ? how to seek a given video source frame accurately via ffmpeg... ?

Answer (score 1):

There is generic support for frame accurate seeking in ffmpeg, but according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5093 it doesn't always work with mpegts / mpegps streams (because ffmpeg estimates the file position with the frame but doesn't handle the case where the estimated file position is too far).

The bug report mentions a workaround that works for me:

`ffmpeg -ss 3.00 -itsoffset -2 -i input -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg`

The value after `-ss` is two seconds before the required timestamp (because of the `-itsoffset -2` argument). So this command extracts the frame at time 5.00

This works because the estimated file position is now based on the two second earlier time, which makes sure the file position isn't too far.

Comment: so how would I know the offset needed ? we got thousands of timestamps of frames from video we want to pull and we only got the exact timestamp...

Comment: the -2 offset should always work, it's only to make sure the position estimation works correctly.